# How to fix issue with Enterprise Account?

Tags: ios, enterprise

I am updating in-house app for a client which they have a previous version currently on over 200+ devices of company.

I want update new version app, but when I try to sign the app with the distribution provisioning profile it asks me for the private key.

After searching, people suggested to revoke the old certificate and generate a new one on the machine. File build success, but some devices install failed.

How to fix this issue ?

Logs :

> Jun 26 10:22:29 DungNguyens-iPhone installd[76] : 0x100794000
>   -[MICodeSigningVerifier performValidationWithError:]: 188: Failed to verify code signature of  : 0xe8008018 (Invalid
>   signing certificate (it may have expired or been revoked)) Jun 26
>   10:22:29 DungNguyens-iPhone installd[76] : 0x100794000
>   -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Verification stage failed Jun 26 10:22:29 DungNguyens-iPhone
>   mobile_installation_proxy[1398] : 0x10050c000
>   __MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices_block_invoke240: Returned error Error Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=13 "Failed to verify
>   code signature of  : 0xe8008018 (Invalid
>   signing certificate (it may have expired or been revoked))"
>   UserInfo=0x12c675570 {LibMISErrorNumber=-402620392,
>   LegacyErrorString=ApplicationVerificationFailed, SourceFileLine=188,
>   FunctionName=-[MICodeSigningVerifier performValidationWithError:],
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to verify code signature of
>    : 0xe8008018 (Invalid
>   signing certificate (it may have expired or been revoked))}

Answer (score 0):

Register the devices which are not able to run the app.

- Click Add device then add device UDID
- Then edit your provisioning profile select all devices.
- use that Provisioning profile it will works.

Comment: My company have 200+ devices . Add UDID only 100 Devices.

Comment: The maximum number of each device type that you can register per membership year is:
Apple TV: 100
Apple Watch: 100
iPad: 100
iPhone: 100
iPod Touch: 100